# How do I activate/select/give focus to a listbox control in vb6?

Tags: select, vb6, focus, controls

So let's say I have a listbox called lstFruits, that contains some words in there.
Now let's say I have a string strString which contains "lstFruits" (the name of the listbox).

So strString = "lstFruits".

How do I go from the string to activating and giving focus to the lstFruit listbox?
I know there's lstFruits.Select or lstFruits.Focus....but I want to be able to activate the 
listbox from the string strString....Eventually I'd like strString to contain the name of 1 
listbox out of many possible ones, and give focus to the listbox spelled out by strString.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VB6 version is

```
Me.Controls("lstFruits").SetFocus
```

Documentation: [SetFocus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa244175%28v=vs.60%29.aspx), [Controls collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa234180%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Im not sure if this will work in VB6, i tested it on VB.NET

```
Me.Controls("lstFruits").Focus()
```

Where "Me" represents your form or other "container" control which contains listbox.

Comment: Thank you Kamil for your help! I do appreciate it.